# The number of real solutions of the equation $\cos(\cos(\cos(\cos(x)))) = \sin(\sin(\sin(\sin(x))))$

Tags: trigonometry

The number of real solutions of the equation $$\cos(\cos(\cos(\cos(x)))) = \sin(\sin(\sin(\sin(x))))$$

(I have no clue to solve this problem)

Comment: @AryamanMaithani can please elaborate your working
(i am a jee aspirant and this question came in in our advanced test)
the given answer claims that $\cos(\cos(\cos(\cos(x)))) = \sin(\sin(\sin(\sin(x))))$
has no real solution,

Comment: I think i has no solution, as the maximum value of argument keeps reducing, I'm not very sure about it. But usually these type of problems just look ugly.

Comment: can you please elaborate it @UmbQbify-Key20-

Comment: Strategy: by the functions' symmetries it suffices to consider $x\in[0,\frac\pi2]$. Both iterated functions are increasing on that interval. Estimate them both at say $x=0,\frac\pi4,\frac\pi2$.

Comment: A nice answer for a duplicate is here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/681395/752069

Answer (score 5):

\begin{align*}
\cos(x) &\in [-1,1]  \text{,}  \\
\cos\cos(x) &\in [\cos(1),1]  \text{,}  \\
\cos\cos\cos(x) &\in [\cos\cos(1),\cos(1)]  \text{, and}  \\
\cos\cos\cos\cos(x) &\in [\cos\cos\cos(1),\cos\cos(1)]  \text{.}
\end{align*}

The second line is because cosine is even and attains its maximum, $1$ on the interval $[-1,1]$.  We know $[\cos(1),1]$ only contains positive numbers (because $\cos(0) > 0$ and the least positive angle producing zero from the cosine is $\pi/2 > 1$).

\begin{align*}
\sin(x) &\in [-1,1]  \text{,}  \\
\sin\sin(x) &\in [-\sin(1),\sin(1)]  \text{,}  \\
\sin\sin\sin(x) &\in [-\sin\sin(1),\sin\sin(1)]  \text{, and }  \\
\sin\sin\sin\sin(x) &\in [-\sin\sin\sin(1),\sin\sin\sin(1)]  \text{.}
\end{align*}

This last interval contains positive and negative numbers.

The only way there can be solutions is if the upper bound of the last interval for iterated sines is at least the lower bound of the last interval for iterated cosines.  So, we must decide
$$  \sin\sin\sin(1) \overset{?}{\geq} \cos\cos\cos(1)  $$

One way to resolve this is with a calculator.
\begin{align*}
\sin\sin\sin(1) &= 0.6784304773607402289{\dots}  \text{ and }  \\
\cos\cos\cos(1) &= 0.6542897904977791499{\dots}  \text{.}  
\end{align*}
So the potential remains that there may be solutions.  (And as observed in comments, by periodicity, there are either zero solutions or infinitely many.)

If $\sin(y)$ is going to be as large as the lower bound on the iterated cosines, it is at least as large as $1/2$.  (This may seem like pulling a mysterious constant out of thin air; it is not.  There are three angles in the first quadrant we are responsible for knowing very well.  Their sines are $1/2$, $\sqrt{2}/2$, and $\sqrt{3}/2$.  The other two are too large.)  This requires $\pi/6 < y < 5\pi/6$ (up to an integer multiple of $2\pi$).

If $y = \sin(w)$, since $\pi/6 > 1/2$, the same argument requires $\pi/6 < w < 5\pi/6$ (up to an integer multiple of $2\pi$).  (Now we have $\sin\sin(w) > 1/2$.)

If $w = \sin(z)$, since $\pi/6 > 1/2$, the same argument requires $\pi/6 < z < 5\pi/6$ (up to an integer multiple of $2\pi$).  (Now we have $\sin\sin\sin(z) > 1/2$.)

Repeating the argument again, we find that for $\sin\sin\sin\sin(x) > 1/2$ it is the case that $\pi/6 < x < 5\pi/6$ (up to an integer multiple of $2\pi$).  So any solution on $[0,2\pi]$ has $x \in [\pi/6, 5\pi/6]$.

For $x \in [\pi/6, 5\pi/6]$, \begin{align*}
\cos(x) &\in [-1/2,1/2]  \text{,}  \\
 &\vdots  \\
\cos\cos\cos\cos(x) &\in [\cos\cos\cos(1/2),\cos\cos(1)]  \\
    &= [0.698{\dots}, 0.857{\dots}]  \text{.}
\end{align*}

So for the angles where the iterated sine is large enough to meet the range of the iterated cosine, the iterated cosine is greater than the maximum of the iterated sine.  Therefore, there is no solution.

We can also see this from a plot of the two iterated functions.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The upper bound of the orange trace is higher than the lower bound of the blue trace, but whenever the orange trace is $\geq 1/2$, the height of the blue trace is at least $0.698{\dots}$, which is above the upper bound of the orange trace ($0.678{\dots}$).

Comment: Suggestion: state the answer right up front, and then tell the story.

Comment: @uniquesolution : I do not write jokes, stories, or mathematics backwards.  To do so wastes the reader's time.

Comment: You wrote a long argument, taking the reader through lengthy calculations, and you haven't stated the answer to the question: what is the number of solutions to the equation? You may as well just posted the graph. Time wasting? Think again.

Comment: I think it is your prerogative to give the bottom line up front or not, but I point out that ostensibly, it is *not* giving it up front that wastes more time than giving it up.  (Again, I'm not advocating any course of action.)

Comment: @BrianTung : If I were writing a memorandum, which implicitly has the assumption that *understanding* by readers is not required, then a preliminary summary would be justified.  Since mathematics is written under the assumption that understanding is required, a preliminary summary is incorrect.

Comment: @uniquesolution : Although I agree that I omitted a clear statement of the conclusion.  Thanks for the note!  Fixed.

Comment: OK, though "incorrect" sounds like you're prescribing that course of action for others.  I'll choose for myself, thanks! :-)

Comment: Btw, I tried to find complex roots for curiosity numerically, but  no luck, except for guessed real part periodicity like $n \pi i$

Comment: Very nice answer.

Comment: Please search for dupes before answering a dupe.

Comment: $\cos(1)\leq\cos\cos\cos(x)\leq\cos\cos(1).$