# An inequality involving $\cos(\cos(\cos(\cos(2\pi x))))-\cos(\cos(\cos(\cos(2\pi ))))$

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, exponentiation

It's the last post of the day so :

> > Let $0<x<1$ then we have :
> >     $$(1-x^{4(1-x)^2}-(1-x)^{4x^2})^{\frac{6}{5}}\geq \Big(\frac{\cos(\cos(\cos(\cos(2\pi x))))-\cos(\cos(\cos(\cos(2\pi ))))}{2}\Big)^2$$

I try series expansion but it becomes awful .

I know that :

For $0<x<1$ :
$$(1-x^{4(1-x)^2}-(1-x)^{4x^2})\geq 0$$
The proof is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2176571/if-ab-1-so-a4b2b4a2-leq1)

The equality case are $x=0$ and $x=1$ and $x=0.5$

Maybe [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/589663/how-prove-this-inequality-sin-sin-sin-sinx-le-frac45-cos-cos-cos) could be useful .

Maybe we can generalize this with the Dottie number.

I have not the time to continue so ...

Thanks a lot for sharing your time and knowledge .